# How to convert attribute xml to element xml for import in Access without loosing data

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I am new to xml and xsl so I'll try to explain my problem.
I have this type of xml, it is attribute centric and those doesn't import into Access. How to convert attribute data to element data?
Here is a part of xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Catalogue version="3.0">
<App action="A" id="1">
    <BaseVehicle id="1"/>
    <Note>Use Separate Enclosed Connector</Note>
    <Note>Slightly longer than original</Note>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
    <PartType id="8852"/>
    <MfrLabel>CleanWipe</MfrLabel>
    <Position id="104"/>
    <Part>18CW</Part>
</App>
<App action="A" id="2">
    <BaseVehicle id="1"/>
    <BodyType id="6"/>
    <Note>Use Separate Enclosed Connector</Note>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
    <PartType id="8852"/>
    <MfrLabel>SuperWipe</MfrLabel>
    <Position id="30"/>
    <Part>22SW</Part>
</App>
</Catalogue>
```

This is the xsl I used for importing xml into Access
(I don't really understand how it works, I found it here on stackflow):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Problem is I lose App ID. Is there a way to import in Access this data and to have App ID in a column?
Also I have a problem with "Note" lines, because there are more than one Note line per "App", I couldn't import all Note lines. Do you have a suggestion how to import this xml without losing any data?
Thank you all!!!

Edit:
Here is the list I expect after import in Access:

ID  BaseVehicle Note            Qty PartType    MfrLabel    Position    Part    BodyType

1   1           Slightly longer than original   1   8852        CleanWipe   104         18CW
1   1           Use Separate Enclosed Connector 1   8852        CleanWipe   104         18CW
2   1           Use Separate Enclosed Connector 1   8852        SuperWipe   30          22SW    6

Or like this:

ID BaseVehicle  Note            Qty PartType    MfrLabel    Position    Part    BodyType

1  1          Slightly longer.. + Use Separate E..  1   8852        CleanWipe   104         18CW
2  1          Use Separate Enclosed Connector   1   8852        SuperWipe   30          22SW    6

Problem is I cannot make it import column ID and to combine notes or import non-first notes in a separate line...

Comment: Would it be possible to show the output you are actually expecting in this case? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert attribute-centric xml to element-centric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445975/convert-attribute-centric-xml-to-element-centric)

Comment: Hello, I added how do I expect a table to look like when xml gets imported. Also I read the topic Gord mentioned, and from that post I took xsl I wrote here. But it doesn't apply completely to my problem.

Comment: "*I don't really understand how it works*" I believe *that* is the real problem here.

Comment: I started messing for the first time in my life with xml and xsl a couple of days ago... I read a ton of stuff but it is too advanced for me to comprehend. Sorry... If you know a site where I can learn about this from the beginning, I would appreciate it!

Comment: I have a problem with import of XML in Access, if you are familiar with it, please take a look at this link: [Access 2007 doesn't import all element data from XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272595/access-2007-doesnt-import-all-element-data-from-xml-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer for my question. Here is the XSLT I was looking for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/@*">
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[1]">
    <Note1><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[2]">
    <Note2><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note2>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[3]">
    <Note3><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note3>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[4]">
    <Note4><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note4>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[5]">
    <Note5><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note5>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[6]">
    <Note6><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note6>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[7]">
    <Note7><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note7>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[8]">
    <Note8><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note8>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[9]">
    <Note9><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note9>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[10]">
    <Note10><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note10>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[11]">
    <Note11><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note11>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[12]">
    <Note12><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note12>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[13]">
    <Note13><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note13>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[14]">
    <Note14><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note14>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalogue/App/Note[15]">
    <Note15><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Note15>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This way all Attributes are being transformed into Elements and all "Note" elements that are repeating will be renamed depending on their position in "App" up to 15 occurrences. But since I know there will not be more than 10 occurrences, this will work fine. 15 is just out of precaution.
Here is how it looks after transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalogue>
3.0
<App>
  <action>A</action>
  <id>1</id>
  <BaseVehicle>1</BaseVehicle>
  <Note1>Use Separate Enclosed Connector</Note1>
  <Note2>Slightly longer than original</Note2>
  <Qty>1</Qty>
  <PartType>8852</PartType>
  <MfrLabel>CleanWipe</MfrLabel>
  <Position>104</Position>
  <Part>18CW</Part>
</App>
<App>
  <action>A</action>
  <id>2</id>
  <BaseVehicle>1</BaseVehicle>
  <BodyType>6</BodyType>
  <Note1>Use Separate Enclosed Connector</Note1>
  <Qty>1</Qty>
  <PartType>8852</PartType>
  <MfrLabel>SuperWipe</MfrLabel>
  <Position>30</Position>
  <Part>22SW</Part>
</App>
</Catalogue>
```

Comment: I have a problem with import of XML in Access, if you are familiar with it, please take a look at this link: [Access 2007 doesn't import all element data from XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272595/access-2007-doesnt-import-all-element-data-from-xml-file)