# Adding new element on top of XML data via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XML and XSLT so I need little bit of help. I have this kind of XML:

```
<Catalogue>
     <App id="1">
         <Car>BMW</Car>
         <BodyType>Sedan</BodyType>
         <PartType>Wiper</PartType>
         <PartNumber>1234</PartNumber>
     </App>
     <App id="2">
         <Car>Dodge</Car>
         <DriveType>FWD</DriveType>
         <PartType>Wiper</PartType>
         <PartNumber>5678</PartNumber>
     </App>
     <App id="3">
         <Car>Chevrolet</Car>
         <EngineVIN>G</EngineVIN>
         <PartType>Wiper</PartType>
         <PartNumber>9012</PartNumber>
     </App>
     <App id="4">
         <Car>VW</Car>
         <PartType>Wiper</PartType>
         <PartNumber>3456</PartNumber>
     </App>
</Catalogue>
```

I can't figure out how to write a XSLT to add top App with id=0 so it would look like this:

```
<Catalogue>
     <App id="0">
         <Car></Car>
         <BodyType></BodyType>
         <DriveType></DriveType>
         <EngineVIN></EngineVIN>
         <PartType></PartType>
         <PartNumber></PartNumber>
     </App>
     <App id="1">
         <Car>BMW</Car>
         <BodyType>Sedan</BodyType>
         <PartType>Wiper</PartType>
         <PartNumber>1234</PartNumber>
     </App>
     <App id="2">
         <Car>Dodge</Car>
         <DriveType>FWD</DriveType>
         <PartType>Wiper</PartType>
         <PartNumber>5678</PartNumber>
     </App>
     <App id="3">
         <Car>Chevrolet</Car>
         <EngineVIN>G</EngineVIN>
         <PartType>Wiper</PartType>
         <PartNumber>9012</PartNumber>
     </App>
     <App id="4">
         <Car>VW</Car>
         <PartType>Wiper</PartType>
         <PartNumber>3456</PartNumber>
     </App>
</Catalogue>
```

I am trying for couple of days now with no luck, so any help would be appreciated. I need this because when I want to import this XML into Access, for some reason if in first "App" all fields aren't defined (which occur in other "App"-s), they don't get imported.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the set of the tags under `<App id="0">` fixed or is this supposed to be a dynamic union of all tags used under the other `<App>` tags?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Well, it is dynamic depending of a XML i receive, but my idea is to add them fixed. Because I am a beginner with XSLT I was thinking to add all tags possible regardless of the XML I receive. I have no idea how I would do it dynamically. Also I don't know if I can use XSLT 2.0, I don't know does Access 2007 work with XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are satisfied with a fixed set of tags it can be done in XSLT 1.0 quite easily as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="/Catalogue">
  <Catalogue>

    <App id="0">
      <Car></Car>
      <BodyType></BodyType>
      <DriveType></DriveType>
      <EngineVIN></EngineVIN>
      <PartType></PartType>
      <PartNumber></PartNumber>
    </App>

    <xsl:copy-of select="App"/>

  </Catalogue>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that I added closing tags for `<App>`. These were missing in your XML file.

Comment: @Marcus Rickert: Can I kindly ask you for little bit more help? Answer you posted here works, but I need to integrate it into another problem which is on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272595/access-2007-doesnt-import-all-element-data-from-xml-file). Anyway I need to add this <App id="0"> to a more complex XML than I posted here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Can you please take a look at my other question on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272595/access-2007-doesnt-import-all-element-data-from-xml-file). Thank you!