# Convert Attribute to Node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert attrivbute value to node in new xml

Example:
Input Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filecontent>
<work>
    <Field name="Content Title">Title1</Field>
    <Field name="Job Opening">Job Value</Field>
    <Field name="Date Opened">Date Opened Value</Field>
    <Field name="Place">Place Value</Field>
</work>
</filecontent>
```

Output Xml need as below:

```
<filecontent>
<work>
    <ContentTitle>Title1</ContentTitle>
    <JobOpening>Job Value</JobOpening>
    <DateOpened>Date Opened Value</DateOpened>
    <Place>Industry Value</Place>
</work>
</filecontent>
```

And what every value comes inside the node should have as it is.

Comment: See if this can get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445975/convert-attribute-centric-xml-to-element-centric

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Thanks @YitzhakKhabinsky I just updated the original post input xml and output xml that I am expecting.

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this (rather trivial) problem? I pointed you to an example that's very similar to yours. Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to adapt it. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: I am exaclty stuck where I am not able to replace <Field to input.xml attribute value with for each. Thats my exact problem. I am not able to access the attribute name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming XSLT version 1.0.

It's simply a matter of using the [`xsl:element`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element) statement to create a new element with a name that's calculated based on the `@name` attribute of the `Field`.

Using an [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) for the `@name` attribute of the `xsl:element` means the new element's name can be dynamically calculated at runtime.

Within the attribute value template, the [XPath function `translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) is used to remove any spaces from the `@name`.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- rename Field elements based on their @name attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="Field[@name]">
    <!-- discard spaces in the name -->
    <xsl:element name="{translate(@name, ' ', '')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- identity template to copy everything else unchanged -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what exactly looking for, I had a problem with xPath function translate and now its working as per your answers. Thanks a lot